# get multiple values from table1, change them to values based on table2 and write the result to table1

Tags: php, mysql

hi
i can rewrite a column's values in a mysql databse based on another columns values, but this time i need to do this with a twist...
there are two tables (and multiple values at once): **specifications** and **products**.

**products** has two columns: `specificationids` and `specificationorderids`
**specifications** has two columns aswell: `id` and `specificationorder`

`specificationids` has multiple values formatted like this: ,31,29,27,18,
these are also the `id` in the **specifications** table. each `id` has a `specificationorder` value (same row, other column). now what i want to do is, that i want to swap the values of the `id` with the value of `specificationorder` and write these to `specificationorderids` in the **products** table in the same format.
ofcourse this process has to loop through all the id's in the **products** table.

i hope i made the problem clear and understandable

thanks for your help!

Comment: *`specificationids` has multiple values formatted like this: `,31,29,27,18,`*. Oh boy, you really need to read about normalization before continuing on this road.

Comment: Agree with @ypercube. Your query is complicated simply because of this. Consider a one to many relationship table.

Answer (score 0):

Swap **id** and **specificationorder**, **specificationorder** writen in **specificationorderids** if I understand you:

```
<?php
/*  Swap id and specificationorder */
$sql = "SELECT id, specificationorder from specifications";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
$id = $row[0];
$sporder = $row[1];
$sql = "UPDATE specifications SET id=$id, specificationorder=$sporder WHERE id=$id";
mysql_query($sql);
}

/* specificationorder writen in specificationorderids */
$sql = "SELECT specificationorder from specifications";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
$sporder = $row[0];
$sql = "INSERT INTO products(specificationorderids) VALUES($sporder)";
mysql_query($sql);
}
?>
```

Comment: hi. thanks for the code, but its still not completely what i was looking for. right now this code inserts the specificationorders into the product table in new rows. ive made a picture of what i really meant. i found it easier this way to describe the problem just to avoid future musinderstandings :) http://img822.imageshack.us/i/specm.png/ this is the image. what is given is the 'id' and 'specificationorder' in the specifications table and the 'specificationids' in the product table. so from these three combined i want to fill the 'specificationorderids' (marked on the image).any suggestions?

Comment: I guest to you to redesign your database model, you will have seriously problems in future.

Answer (score 0):

for the past couple days i havent been able to come up with a normal code, so heres what ive got so far. ive added comments so you know what i was thinking when experimenting with the code... as in my previous comment i include an image of what i want to achive:  img822.imageshack.us/i/specm.png

```
//get specificationids 
$sql = "SELECT specificationids from products";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$spids = $row[0];

//get specifications
$sql2 = "SELECT id from specifications";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
$row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result2);
$spid = $row2[0];

//get specificationorder
$sql3 = "SELECT specificationorder from specifications";
$result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
$row3 = mysql_fetch_row($result3);
$sporder = $row3[0];

//if the value of specificationids matches a specificationid, then....
while(VALUES($spids)==$spid)
{
$spids=$sporder; //...it should be replaced by the specificationorder
//and then update the specificationorderids column accordingly
$sql = "UPDATE products(specificationorderids) VALUES($spids)";
mysql_query($sql);
}
```